# Как кликом по одной кнопке снять галки со всех чекбоксов формы?

Tags: javascript, html, css

В форме много чекбоксов, и есть кнопка "очистить", которая должна снимать галочки со всех чекбоксов. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 6):

```js
NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;

document.getElementById("clear").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  var formBlock = document.getElementById("formId");
  var inputArr = formBlock.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");
  inputArr.forEach(function(el) {
    el.checked = false;
  });
});
```

```html
<form id="formId" >
  <input type="checkbox" name="option1" value="a1" checked>1
  <Br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="option2" value="a2" checked>2
  <Br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="option3" value="a3" checked>3
  <Br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="option4" value="a4">4
  <Br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="option5" value="a5">5
</form>
<div id="clear">Очистить</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

На столь простой вопрос ответ быстрее найти самостоятельно http://javascript.ru/forum/jquery/52170-snyat-galochki-so-vsekh-chekboksov.html

циклом по всем нужным элементам

```
$('[name^="access"]').prop({'checked': false})
```